# SAS. if then do

Tags: sas

```
data A B;
 set data c;
 if var>1 then output A;
 else if var<1 then do;
 output B;
 indicator = data_b;
 end;
run;
```

I want to separate data c into data A and B. For data b, I want to add an extra column called indicator, and the value of this columns are the same: data_b (character values);

However, the program can run through but the values in column indicator are missing. Where did I make mistake? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of `indicator` AFTER you output the observations to the data sets.  Try moving that line BEFORE the `OUTPUT` statement.